# Whats the problem with my laptop? cant start Ubuntu

Tags: boot

While trying to start my Lenovo laptop I get the screen you see in the image below, I’m not able to to do any other thing or get the Ubuntu console. Also I'm not able to start using the Ubuntu CD.

[image]

Comment: Hit enter at this screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that your keyboard is broken. I had similar problem with my Lenovo. Try to check with external keyboard via USB. Also check buttons delete, F2, F8, F12 or another, which could start this menu. One of this button can be mechanically pressed.

Answer (score 0):

If this screen happen all the time you boot your laptop one time boot option/ key might be pressed . Meaning F12 key might be crashed. Check if this happen to your key board. But if every thing is ok, then choose the first on the list /ATA HDD0/ and enter. If this works, the rest will be easy.

Good luck with that.

Comment: The keyboard seems to be OK, if I select ATA HDD0 nothing happens the screen appears again

Comment: Hello there again. If the keyboard seems fine then try booting your computer from live USB drive often bootable media with windows environment like Spotmau boot suit or Hiren boot. Then choose USB from boot menu option. It will show windows environment. Please, then, exhaustively test every tool related with windows start up.